# how to get value from xml and set to integer

Tags: android, variables, integer, android-xml

i just want to know that how can i get a value from `layout.xml` and set it to int variable.

what does i mean is, example:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/grid_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>


public class AppConst {
public static final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = android:numColumns;
}
```

i want to access number of column from layout.xml because i have landscape and portrait layout.

landscape column=4; and portrait column=2;

so i can access number of column depending on landscape or portrait mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the column count set in xml using its instance.

```
myGridView.getNumColumns();
```

If you need to set the column count dynamically use

```
myGridView.setNumColumns(count);
```

Its related XML Attributes

```
android:numColumns
```

More info is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#getNumColumns%28%29)

**EDIT** Save it like this. This code should be in the activity/fragment where the grid view is loaded

```
GridView myGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.my_grid_view);
AppConst.NUM_OF_COLUMNS = myGridView.getNumColumns();
```

Comment: do you mean like this
`public static final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS =myGridView.getNumColumns();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getNumColumns(](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#getNumColumns%28%29)). You don't need to know device orientation, just apply given method to your GridView